# How to format time from dd:hh:mm:ss to only hh:mm:ss in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I found SQL function which get second as input parameter and return seconds in dd:hh:mm:ss format e-g for `93600` seconds it returns `1:02:00:00`

it means 1 day 2 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

Function that i used is :

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[udfTimeSpanFromSeconds]
(
    @Seconds int
)
RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    --Variable to hold our result
      @DHMS varchar(15)
    --Integers for doing the math
    , @Days int --Integer days
    , @Hours int --Integer hours
    , @Minutes int --Integer minutes
    --Strings for providing the display
    , @sDays varchar(5) --String days
    , @sHours varchar(2) --String hours
    , @sMinutes varchar(2) --String minutes
    , @sSeconds varchar(2) --String seconds

--Get the values using modulos where appropriate
SET @Hours = @Seconds/3600
SET @Minutes = (@Seconds % 3600) /60
SET @Seconds = (@Seconds % 3600) % 60

--If we have 24 or more hours, split the @Hours value into days and hours
IF @Hours > 23 
BEGIN
    SET @Days = @Hours/24
    SET @Hours = (@Hours % 24)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Days = 0
END

--Now render the whole thing as string values for display
SET @sDays = convert(varchar, @Days)
SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Hours), 2)
SET @sMinutes = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Minutes), 2)
SET @sSeconds = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Seconds), 2)

--Concatenate, concatenate, concatenate
SET @DHMS =  @sDays + ':' + @sHours + ':' + @sMinutes + ':' + @sSeconds

RETURN @DHMS

END
```

and select command that will retrieve output is

```
select dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds('93600' )
```

it shows me result as:

[image]

Now i need this output in `hh:mm:ss` format e-g for current example `26:00:00` it means 26 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

I am using SQL server 2008. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is as simple as removing your if condition. if condition converts hour to days. so removing it will solve your problem. i didn't check it though but i think it will work.

Comment: Do you want the expected result from the output of the function? Or do you want to modify logic in the function itself?

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai, After removal of if it return me null.

Comment: Did you remove `@sDays + ':' + ` from `SET @DHMS =  @sDays + ':' + @sHours + ':' + @sMinutes + ':' + @sSeconds` statement?

Comment: @Jesuraja, i want it from function.

Comment: *return null*... I think, you didn't assign value for `@sDays`.

Comment: @Jesuraja, i remove it but when i entered "360000" which are 100 hours then it return me 00:00:00.

Comment: Please check this `SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Hours), 2)`...    Right(..., 2), so that you getting like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with math

```
DECLARE @sec INT = 93600

SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@sec / 3600)) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ((@sec % 3600) / 60)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (@sec % 60)), 2)
```

---

Written as a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(
    @sec INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@sec / 3600)) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ((@sec % 3600) / 60)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (@sec % 60)), 2)
END
```

Sample call:

```
SELECT dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(360000)
```

RESULT:

```
100:00:00
```

Comment: This is working perfectly upto millions of seconds, thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you function to return hh:mm:ss then it needs to be as below. This does however limit the total time to be less than 100 hours. You can fix this by increasing the length of the Hours String by changing the right clause and increasing the length of the string returned, as I have now done to illustrate.

(Normally once you have summed your time you usually divide the total by 3600.00 to produce a decimal value for use in further calculations, for example if you are paying by the hour)

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[udfTimeSpanFromSeconds]
(
    @Seconds int
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    --Variable to hold our result
      @HMS varchar(15)
    --Integers for doing the math
    , @Hours int --Integer hours
    , @Minutes int --Integer minutes
    --Strings for providing the display
    , @sHours varchar(2) --String hours
    , @sMinutes varchar(2) --String minutes
    , @sSeconds varchar(2) --String seconds

--Get the values using modulos where appropriate
SET @Hours = @Seconds/3600
SET @Minutes = (@Seconds % 3600) /60
SET @Seconds = (@Seconds % 3600) % 60

--Now render the whole thing as string values for display
SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(5), @Hours), 3)
SET @sMinutes = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(3), @Minutes), 2)
SET @sSeconds = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(3), @Seconds), 2)

--Concatenate, concatenate, concatenate
SET @HMS =  @sHours + ':' + @sMinutes + ':' + @sSeconds

RETURN @HMS

END
```

Comment: when I enter "360000" seconds which are 100 hours then it return me 00:00:00.

Comment: You should never use `varchar` without a length in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context, and errors of this sort are very hard to find.

Comment: The maximum result the function can return is 99:59:59 or 359999 seconds

Comment: @Ewan, So you mean that greater than or equal to 100 hours are unable to convert ?

Comment: Hi Wagas I have now changed it so that it will return up to 999:59:59

Comment: @Ewan, Thanks for your time sir , I got solution from wewesthemenace post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return 100 hours then you have to use it:-

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[udfTimeSpanFromSeconds]
(
    @Seconds int
)
RETURNS varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
--Variable to hold our result
  @HMS varchar(15)
--Integers for doing the math
, @Hours int --Integer hours
, @Minutes int --Integer minutes
--Strings for providing the display
, @sHours varchar(3) --String hours
, @sMinutes varchar(2) --String minutes
, @sSeconds varchar(2) --String seconds

--Get the values using modulos where appropriate

SET @Hours = @Seconds/3600
SET @Minutes = (@Seconds % 3600) /60
SET @Seconds = (@Seconds % 3600) % 60

--Now render the whole thing as string values for display
SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Hours), 3)
SET @sMinutes = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Minutes), 2)
SET @sSeconds = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Seconds), 2)

--Concatenate, concatenate, concatenate
SET @HMS =  @sHours + ':' + @sMinutes + ':' + @sSeconds

RETURN @HMS

END
```

Comment: it's not working giving same result 00:00:00, I need to add 24 on each 1 days increament.

Comment: actually "SET @sHours = RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar, @Hours), 2)" line gives 2 chars from right, resulting in 00 instaed of 100. i have changed it to 3. so it will return as 100.

Comment: if you want it generalize, you have to change your code