# Return greater then 24 hours in hh:mm:ss format in SQL server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have `View` in `SQL` name as `vw_Rept_Attend` and column names as

```
 UserID (int),WorkHrs (varchar),ExtraHrs varchar(), AtnDate (datetime), EmpName (varchar), 
EmpType (varchar), UserName (varchar),Role (varchar)
```

actual working on `WorkHrs` and `ExtraHrs`

so what i am doing with this is

i stored daily working time of employees in `WorkHrs` and extra hours in `ExtraHrs`, then i am showing attendance summary report between two dates provided through filter,

obviously i did maximum of things with your experts suggestions and application is working fine for small data and on client testing i got an issue that i didn't consider at that time

**Issue description**

every employee has to work 9 hours per day (daily work hours)

working hours (login time)

extra hours (daily work hours - working hours)

if employee works `6 hours` so his extra hours will be `-3 hours` negative because of less working time than required time and i got this result by this `c#` statement

```
wrktime= workinghrs.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(time).TimeOfDay);
TimeSpan Daily_work = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
 TimeSpan exthrs = Convert.ToDateTime(wrktime).TimeOfDay.Subtract(Daily_work);
```

and this will give me in negative when any one worked less than `9 hours`

so if user do this for `300 days` and every day `-3 hours` are added to `database` result will be `-900 hours` for `300 days`

i read all this record using following `sqlprocedure` to show on crystal report

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Rpt_Emps_Attnd]
    @strt date,
    @end date
AS

    begin
    with cte
as
( select   UserID,
            WorkHrs,
         case when left(ExtraHrs,1)='-' then -1 else 1 end as multiply,
            right(ExtraHrs,8) as timestring,
            --get hours in seconds:
            DATEPART(HOUR,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 3600 AS h_in_s,
            --get minutes in seconds:
            DATEPART(MINUTE,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 60 AS m_in_s,
            --get seconds:
            DATEPART(SECOND,right(ExtraHrs,8)) AS s,AtnDate,EmpName,EmpType,
            UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate

  from      vw_Rept_Attend
)

select   UserID,dbo.udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(Sum(Left(workhrs,2) * 3600 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 4,2) * 60 + substring(Convert(varchar(8),workhrs), 7,2))) as WorkHrs ,
case when sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply) < 0
            then '-' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,ABS(sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply)),0),114) 

            else CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(s,sum((c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s) * multiply),0),114)
        end as ExtraHrs ,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,convert(VARCHAR(10),StartDate,105) as StartDate,convert(VARCHAR(10),EndDate,105) as EndDate

from    cte c  where  convert(date,AtnDate) between @strt and @end   
group by UserID,EmpName,EmpType,UserName, Role,StartDate,EndDate
  Order by UserID
    end
```

and function for calculating sum of all `WorkHrs` between dates as

```
    ALTER FUNCTION udfTimeSpanFromSeconds(
        @sec INT
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
    AS
    BEGIN

RETURN 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@sec / 3600)) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ((@sec % 3600) / 60)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (@sec % 60)), 2)
END
```

this i got from my question on `stack` [How to format time from dd:hh:mm:ss to only hh:mm:ss in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429701/how-to-format-time-from-ddhhmmss-to-only-hhmmss-in-sql-server)

but the portion of calculating sum of `ExtHrs` which is part of `stored procedure` which i mention above i-e

```
case when left(ExtraHrs,1)='-' then -1 else 1 end as multiply,
            right(ExtraHrs,8) as timestring,
            --get hours in seconds:
            DATEPART(HOUR,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 3600 AS h_in_s,
            --get minutes in seconds:
            DATEPART(MINUTE,right(ExtraHrs,8)) * 60 AS m_in_s,
            --get seconds:
            DATEPART(SECOND,right(ExtraHrs,8)) AS s
```

only support `24 hours`e-g if result is `27 hours` then it display `3 hours` and if it is `-56 hours` then it display `-8 hours`

i use `SQL Server 2008`,

i think enough description to understand but if any of you don't understand then please freely ask me to share code or any logic that i used.

your help will be appreciated,

thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

this question [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000) is totally different because i am not asking about which `datatype` should i use

here application can get negative time value e-g -3 hours that i explained very clearly and `timespan` datatype do not accept negative sign.

now i think it should clear

**Update**
in my database it looks like

[image]

so after calculation `ExtHrs` should be `-31:50:46` but it display `-7:50:46`

i think this is because of not supporting greater than `24 hours`

Comment: can you throw some sample data like only Extrahr and workhr data and what output you are expecting ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh, please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW there are so many technical flaws in proc as well as data type that you are using.Real Problem is here.

1. In your proc you can put where date condition in first CTE itself.
2. If possible you can store extrahour in second in table.That means Extrahours is int or bigint.like -1000 or 1000.varchar will never solve your problem.It will save you from lot of conversion hence fast.
3. Using so many columns in group by is itself wrong approach.specially using varchar column in group by.You should use key column in group by then join again with table to get other columns in resultset.

with your sample data I am  getting -29:-51:-30.0 instead of -31:50:46 .
do it this way,

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ExtraHrs VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('00:59:38')
    ,('-03:59:37')
    ,('-08:59:39')
    ,('-08:52:36')
    ,('-08:59:16');

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ExtraHrs
        ,CASE 
            WHEN left(ExtraHrs, 1) = '-'
                THEN - 1
            ELSE 1
            END AS multiply
        ,right(ExtraHrs, 8) AS timestring
        ,
        --get hours in seconds:
        DATEPART(HOUR, right(ExtraHrs, 8)) * 3600 AS h_in_s
        ,
        --get minutes in seconds:
        DATEPART(MINUTE, right(ExtraHrs, 8)) * 60 AS m_in_s
        ,
        --get seconds:
        DATEPART(SECOND, right(ExtraHrs, 8)) AS s
    FROM @t
    )
    ,CTE3
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,c.h_in_s + c.m_in_s + c.s AddExtra
    FROM cte c
    )
    ,cte4
AS (
    SELECT sum(AddExtra * multiply) mn
    FROM cte3
    )
    ,cte5
AS (
    SELECT mn / 3600 hh
        ,(mn % 3600) / 60 mi
        ,(mn % 3600.0) % 60 ss
    FROM cte4
    )
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN hh < 0
            THEN '-'
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,cast(hh AS VARCHAR) + ':' + cast(mi AS VARCHAR) + ':' + cast(ss AS VARCHAR)
FROM cte5
```

> Try this for leading zero,
>
> > Declare @i int=5 SELECT REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(@i)) + cast(@i as varchar)

Comment: i need some time to understand and implement this then i will update you, thanks for your time and effort,

Comment: its working fine but a little issue i get "-02:37:12" as "-2:-37:-12.0", It should be only "-02:37:12" format not -ive with mins and seconds,

Comment: gimme time.So only formating is an issue ? ok ? Also don't use so many cte as i have use.That much not require.I correct the format and post it.

Comment: is it possible to use only one cte that i used in my question or how can i use function to calculated this as i used for workHrs, if this possible then plz edit your answer, i am w8ing for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

`ExtraHrs` is a string. So is `right(ExtraHrs,8)`. Then how do you get the idea of using a datetime function (namely `DATEPART`) on it? You shouldn't do this.

Now in what format is `ExtraHrs`? You seem to expect an optional (?) sign followed by 8 characters for hh:mm:ss.

With string functions and casts to numberic values you'd get:

```
case when left(extrahrs, 1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end * -- sign
( 
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 1, 2) as int) * 3600) + -- hours
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 4, 2) as int) * 60) + -- minutes
  (cast(substring(right(extrahrs, 8), 7, 2) as int)) + -- seconds
) as secs
```

This allows for time spans up to almost 100 hours. For more hours your format would have to change to hhh:mm:ss or even variable length.

Comment: thanks for your attention here sir, SQL don't allow me to update procedure and throw an error that "substr is not a recognized built in function name" any suggestions,?

Comment: Hi waqas. change it to SUBSTRING and not substr. I've edited the answer but I'm waiting for it to be peer reviewed

Comment: @TheDanMan: Thank you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, will you please edit my procedure , i change it but i got error that "Invalid column name h_in_s,Invalid column name m_in_s, Invalid column namemultiply", it take my more than 5 days of research, thanks